# SQL: grouping by column after sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

Given a table structure with `name` and `rank` columns, with the possibility of there being duplicates for `name`, how can I get the rows unique by `name`, with maximum `rank`?

For example, assuming the following data:

```
+-------+-------+
| name  | rank  |
+-------+-------+
| a     | 1     |
| a     | 2     |
| b     | 10    |
| b     | 20    |
| c     | 100   |
| c     | 200   |
+-------+-------+
```

The query should return:

```
+-------+-------+
| a     | 2     |
| b     | 20    |
| c     | 200   |
+-------+-------+
```

I have the following solution that is extremely slow, which I suspect is O(N^2).

```
SELECT name, 
       rank 
FROM   books temp1 
WHERE  rank = (SELECT max(rank) 
                      FROM   book temp2 
                      WHERE  temp1.name = temp2.name)
```

Can it be improved? Is there an altogether better way to do this?

I'm using MySQL, and this will eventually have to be translated to JPA, so if there's a JPA/Hibernate idiom for this that would also be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select name, max(rank) as MaxRank
    from books
    group by name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name 
     , MAX(rank) AS rank
  FROM books
 GROUP BY name
```

That's the simplest query to return the result set in your example.

Comment: you have an extra comma after `name`

Answer (score 1):

Normally all you would need is a standard group by

```
SELECT name, 
       max(rank) as rank
FROM   books temp1
GROUP BY name
```

But since it is MySQL, there is also an alternative

```
SELECT name, 
       rank
FROM   (
    SELECT name, rank
    FROM books
    ORDER BY name, rank desc) ordered
GROUP BY name
```